# ASP.Net Scheduler Service Time Delay Drift After Running for 1-Day

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is anyone able to see something obvious here as to why this might be occurring?  I can run it daily with a button click and get exact scheduler execution timing per the specified times, but when I leave it running ongoing, there is a drift in the time of earlier execution.  i.e., I click the start button on 3.17.2021 (any time in the day) and methods execute at the specified time periods;  on 3.18.2021 after being left running for an 24-hour period, the scheduled methods all execute approximately 23 minutes before the specified time period.

I can click the button daily if I needed to for proper execution time, but the required result is that it executes daily at the exact same time after the initial 'start period' without any type of manual interaction from there on.  The calculations seem sound, so there isn't anything apparent to me as to why this might be happening.  It works great when executed daily, but not if left to go on 'by itself.'

Scheduler.cs

```
using mine.Services;
using System;

namespace mine
{
    public class Scheduler
    {

        public static void IntervalInSeconds(int hour, int sec, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval / 3600;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, sec, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInMinutes(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval / 60;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInHours(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }
        public static void IntervalInDays(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
        {
            interval = interval * 24;
            SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
        }


    }
}
```

SchedulerService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace mine.Services
{
    public class SchedulerService
    {
                
        private static SchedulerService _instance;
        private List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();
        private SchedulerService() { }
        public static SchedulerService Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new SchedulerService());
        public void ScheduleTask(int hour, int min, double intervalInHour, Action task)
        {

            DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeZoneInfo centralZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
            DateTime centralTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, centralZone);

            //DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime firstRun = new DateTime(centralTime.Year, centralTime.Month, centralTime.Day, hour, min, 0, 0);

            if (centralTime > firstRun)
            {
                firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
            }
            
            TimeSpan timeToGo = firstRun - centralTime;
            if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
   
            
            var timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                task.Invoke();
            }, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.FromHours(intervalInHour));
            timers.Add(timer);
            
        }

    }
}
```

Implementation

```
protected void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateLabel();

    Scheduler.IntervalInHours(14, 45, 24,
    () => {
        AccessTokenRequest();
    });

    Scheduler.IntervalInHours(14, 58, 24,
    () => {
        //MyMethods();
    });

    Scheduler.IntervalInHours(15, 00, 24,
    () => {
        GetPositions();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here in case it can be helpful to anyone who needs ASP.Net application event scheduling as I had when I came across the above solution.  I found Hangfire that is a far more sophisticated solution, and quite frankly awesome.  Set it an forget it for reoccurring tasks, reliable, and logging-enabled.

https://www.hangfire.io/